# Regulierung nach einem Maß

Tags: preposition

If I want to regulate something in accordance to a certain measure, do I use

> Regulierung **nach** <*measure*>?

For example, if I want to regulate the inclination degree of a bed according to someone's weight, is it *Regulierung nach dem Gewicht*?

Comment: To the downvoters: Please post a short comment to explain why you did downvote the question, to help the poster to write better questions in the future. (I have no idea why you did downvote the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Frage lässt sich nicht so gut allgemeingültig beantworten.

Hier sind wohlgeformte deutsche Sätze, die in deinem Kontext verwendbar und typisch wären:

> Lässt sich das Bett auf das Gewicht des Patienten einstellen?
>
> Stellen Sie die Neigung des Betts entsprechend dem Gewicht des Patienten ein!
>
> Stellen Sie die Neigung des Betts auf das Gewicht des Patienten ein!
>
> Achten Sie darauf, dass die Neigung des Betts fürs das Gewicht des Patienten angemessen ist.
>
> Achten Sie darauf, dass die Neigung des Betts zum Gewicht des Patienten passt.
>
> Regulieren Sie die Neigung des Betts entsprechend dem Gewicht des Patienten.

Oder nehmen wir einen anderen Kontext, hier zur Abwechslung ein Teilchenbeschleuniger.

> Die Steueranlage reguliert den Teilchenstrom entsprechend dem Gewicht der Teilchen.
>
> Die Steueranlage reguliert den Teilchenstrom je nach Gewicht der Teilchen.
>
> Der Teilchenstrom sollte auf das Gewicht der Teilchen eingestellt werden.

Ein Nebenaspekt bei der Beantwortung deiner Frage ist, dass *regulieren* eher selten und wenn, dann eher in sehr technischen Zusammenhängen (wie bei Teilchenbeschleunigern oder bei Elektronik) verwendet wird. Für ein Krankenhausbett kann man es verwenden, aber in der krankenhausbetrieblichen Alltagspraxis wird wohl doch häufiger *einstellen* verwendet.

Grundsätzlich kann man sagen, dass *regulieren nach* eher ungewöhnlich ist. Man würde es verstehen, aber richtig elegant ist es selten.

Ausnahme:

> Regulieren Sie die Luftzufuhr nach gusto.

Aber dies liegt daran, dass *nach gusto* (oder: *nach Geschmack*) eine stehende Wendung ist.

Answer (score 3):

*Regulierung* means there's a knob somewhere where you can "rule" over the thing. If you mean a closed-loop control the term is **Regelung**.

> Die Regelung nach Gewicht des Schläfers ist eine Innovation.

If you want to say the weight isn't only measured but also the energy source for the control loop, write:

> Die Regelung durch das Gewicht des Schläfers ist eine Innovation.

Comment: Durch das Beispiel in der Frage, "... regulate the inclination degree of a bed ...", wird klar, dass der OP tatsächlich _Regulierung_ meint.

Answer (score 1):

Wir neigen dazu Wörter zu verbinden. Die übliche Lösung wäre hier

> Gewichtsregulierung

wie es auch

> Geschwindigkeitsregulierung, Temperaturregelung, Abstandsregelung

usw. gibt.